# JTable with horizontal scrollbar is not working

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable, jscrollpane

I am trying to use a `JScrollPane` with a `JTable` to display data from the database, but when I create it, the horizontal scrollbar is not being displayed, only the vertical scrollbar is displayed.
I have tried

```java
new JScrollPane (tableSingle, ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
```

but this doesn't work either. It shows the scroll bar but does not allow scrolling. I also have tried with

```java
tableSingle.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF)
```

but it is making the width of column smaller and the horizontal scrollbar is still not showing up. I have also tried both of them together but it did not display the horizontal scrollbar. I am new to using *Eclipse*. Please help me. Or how can I display the database in `JTable` into multiple lines?

Here is the code:

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
scrollPane.setBounds(577, 81, 422, 268);
panelSingle.add(scrollPane);

tableSingle = new JTable();
tableSingle.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
                    new Object[][] {
                    },
                    new String[] {
                        "Rules \" Single \""
                    }
                ) {
                    /**
                     * 
                     */
                    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
                    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
                    Class[] columnTypes = new Class[] {
                        String.class
                    };
                    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
                    public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                        return columnTypes[columnIndex];
                    }
                });
tableSingle.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(107);
scrollPane.setViewportView(tableSingle);
```

Comment: Your table model seems incorrect. If you want to display data from the database, then you have to query the database in order to retrieve the data that you want to display in your `JTable`, don't you? I assume you want a separate column in the `JTable` for every column in your SQL query. In the code in your question, there appear to be only two columns in your `JTable`, i.e. **Rules** and **Single**. Is that correct? If you haven't already done so, maybe you should visit [How to Use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

Comment: Are you using [WindowBuilder](https://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/) ?

Comment: Post your [mre] demonstrating the problem. The database is not required for the "MRE". First learn how to do what you want with hard coded data. Then worry about getting the data dynamically.

Comment: No. I have only one column which is Rules Single. I can't get it why my table model is incorrect, please explain to me.

Comment: Yes, I am using WIndowBuilder.